# SharpSvn: Why was update of subfolder from Empty Depth Checkout skipped?

Tags: sharpsvn

I'm having some trouble cherrypicking some folders out of a repo using SharpSvn (from C#).  I did this:

```
client.CheckOut( uri, dir, new SvnCheckOutArgs() { Depth = SvnDepth.Empty } );
foreach( var folder in folders )
{
   client.Update( folder );
}
```

But my second call to `Update` didn't work. It reports that the action was **SvnNotifyAction.Skip** and nothing gets written to the working copy.

*uri* is essentially something like: `svn://myserver/myrepo/mysdk` and *dir* is something like `C:\Test\mysdk`.  (I've changed exact names for the purposes of this question, but structurally it's identical.)

Then the 1st folder is `C:\Test\mysdk\include` (this works)

Then the 2nd folder is `C:\Test\mysdk\bin\v100\x86` (this one doesn't update)

Why would the first one work but when I get the 2nd folder (nested subfolders) it doesn't Update?  It reports that it is skipped?  But I don't know how to figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that updating the nested subdirectory doesn't work because the parent directories don't exist yet and so the nested subdirectory update is skipped.  To fix this, I needed to add an argument to Update to indicate that it should create the parent directories.

(The equivalent svn command line option would be `--parents`).

```
client.Update( folder, new SvnUpdateArgs() { UpdateParents = true } );
```

I discovered this by trying to do it manually from the svn command line (and encountered the same problem.)  `svn help co` offered this tiny clue:  *--parents : make intermediate directories*  I'm assuming that UpdateParents and --parents are equivalent.  So far so good.